# Print Command Without Hitting Enter

Tags: vimscript, command-line, command

Suppose I map a key to enter a command in the command buffer, but without hitting enter:

```
function! BuildSystemTask()
    if inProject() "generic function that checks if I am in a buildable project
        :!make<Space>
    else
        echom("you are not in a valid project, whatever that means")
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>b :BuildSystemTask()<CR>
```

The idea here is that I want to hit my mapping, and I would get "make " in the command buffer so that I can type whatever I want. However, this does not do it because it actually enters the whole command `:!make<Space>` as is in the command buffer.

I also tried `:execute "normal! :make<Space>"` and that didn't work either. It hits `<CR>` at the end.

Any idea how to do this? Or if if there is a better way to invoke a build command (`make` is here as an example. It could be `node` or `go` or `maven`). Or if there is a better way to achieve being able to pass arbitrary build command that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d recommend an `<expr>` mapping—make the following changes:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>b BuildSystemTask()
```

And then in your function:

```
if inProject()
  return ':make! '
else
  return ''
```

An alternative would be to use the `feedkeys()` function